# OCR without pytesseract

Tags: machine-learning, ocr

I want to have a OCR for recognizing specific fonts like Calibri.
I have the dataset from  UCI machine learning repository but the features are based on pixel value rather than pattern.
So even a change in font size /pixel value of the character , results in wrong output(knearest).
I want to have OCR based on the pattern or any other technique which can classify the characters irrespective of the font size of the given character.

Comment: Any specific attempts you have tried in achieving this should be mentioned. Within your tried solutions, you can mention where exactly it is missing your target

Comment: What I have done is 
In text editor I have written one character e.g .&amp;amp;#39; K&amp;amp;#39;
Then I took a screenshot of this letter so as to create image of 20*20 because all the training dataset have pixel data of 20*20 image.So now when I predict results for this character it gives wrong output.How to have generic OCR for specific fonts? I have used knearest algorithm.